# Custom options disappearing

Tags: magento-enterprise, custom-options, debugging, ee-1.12

Dealing with a client who uses Magento Enterprise ver. 1.12.0.2.  I'm not a developer, but I do have a team that manage the issues/website.  Anyways, the client has been reporting that whenever they add custom options to a particular simple product they seem to disappear.

I've heard of this happening back in '09 for community edition, but I wasn't sure if this issue may have been related.  I wanted to ask your help for fixing the problem or possibly replicating it, if you've heard of it before.  I can't see what the client is talking about because the issue hasn't occurred for me.

Methods I've tried:

- Duplicating the product, setting custom options.
- Jumping around tabs when creating the product in the backend then saving.
- Resetting cache countless times and creating new products with custom options and monitoring them on the front end.

Hopefully someone can help and that this is formatted correctly.  Let me know if there are any questions that need to be answered before you can give me a response.

Edit: It DOES seem like its related to the old custom options issue reported back in '09.  Apparently if you don't click directly on the custom options tab when making other changes and saving...it deletes the custom options occasionally or they disappear.  Any ideas?

Comment: I also got into same problem but in CE. Did you figure out the problem?

Comment: I just experienced this problem in CE v1.7. Anyone?